# how to have variable in all view?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, smarty3

I use smarty and ci 3.0.6 can I use a base controller in my core? I do it but I don't have any value in my view

controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
public $stats;
public $title;

public function __construct() {

parent::__construct();

$this->load->model('User_Model');
$var->stats = $this->User_Model->count_Unverified_adviser();
$t=$var->stats->Unverified;
$var->title = 'title';
$this->custom_smarty->assign('vars',$var);
$this->load->vars($var);

}   }
```

my controller that load view:

```
class Adviser extends MY_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('User_Model');

}   
public function index()
{           
    $this->custom_smarty->assign('url',base_url());
    $this->custom_smarty->display('test.tpl');  
}
```

my test.tpl:

```
<td>{$vars.title}</td>
```

Comment: Does Smarty show an error?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving an object to the assign function.

To access `$vars.title` in this way you should give an array:

```
$this->custom_smarty->assign('vars', array( 'title' => 'somevalue' ));
```